# react-pdf, `Save in File`function throws exception

Tags: reactjs

When button clicked reactPdf.render called and it throws the exception pic as below;

Expected Behaviour: Download a file name "example.pdf"

```
import ReactPDF from "@react-pdf/renderer";

    const GenerateBarcode = () => {
        ReactPDF.render(<p>Some Jsx Elements</p>, `${__dirname}/example.pdf`);
      };
    
      return (
        <div>
          <button
                                      className="btn btn-primary "
                                      type="button"
                                      onClick={GenerateBarcode}
                                    >
                                     Generator PDF
                                    </button>
    ...
```

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

solution: https://github.com/diegomura/react-pdf/issues/283#issuecomment-412233870
Basically you are using a `node` lib in the web `environment` as the comment states.

Comment: He's using the file saving approach, see here: https://github.com/diegomura/react-pdf#node-save-in-a-file

Comment: Yup that looks like it! You should change your answer to that so it can be marked as correct one